# use $httpProvider.responseInterceptors in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want use `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` in a rails application, but when I add this to project, I get below error in chrome console and project isn't run.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/$injector/nomod?p0=app angular.min.js?body=1:7
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:7
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:22
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:23
(anonymous function) recordService.js?body=1:4
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Type…0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fassets%2Fapp.js%3Fbody%...<omitted>...9) angular.min.js?body=1:7
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:7
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:36
q angular.min.js?body=1:8
f angular.min.js?body=1:35
Cb angular.min.js?body=1:38
d angular.min.js?body=1:19
ec angular.min.js?body=1:19
pd angular.min.js?body=1:18
(anonymous function) angular.min.js?body=1:223
fire jquery.js?body=1:3120
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:3232
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js?body=1:3444
completed jquery.js?body=1:3475
```

I use `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` in my `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'sessionService', 'recordService'])
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
            var interceptor = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$q', function($location, $rootScope, $q) {
                function success(response) {
                    return response
                };

                function error(response) {
                    if (response.status == 401) {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
                        $location.path('/users/login');
                        return response;
                    };
                    return $q.reject(response);
                };

                return function(promise) {
                    return promise.then(success, error);
                };
            }];

            $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
        }])
        .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/',               {controller: 'HomeCtrl',    templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/index.html') %>'})
                    .when('/record',         {controller: 'RecordCtrl',  templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/record/alaki.html') %>'})
                    .when('/users/login',    {controller: 'UsersCtrl',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/users/login.html') %>'})
                    .when('/users/register', {controller: 'UsersCtrl',   templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('templates/users/register.html') %>'})
                    .otherwise(              {redirectTo: '/'});
        }]);
```

If I remove `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor)` from js file, the problem is fixed, but I want to use this line, where is the problem in this code? How can I solve this problem?
`NOTE`: `sessionService` and `recordService` are 2 `js` file that I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user the `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptor');`instead of `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);`and also make sure that angular version is 1.2.19 or above after you change the code

Comment: did you add the one for Cookies ?

Comment: Your answer is right, just replace `('interceptor')` with `(interceptor)`.

Comment: Project is run, but I get another error, `Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.14/$injector/nomod?p0=app`. Do you know the reasons?

Comment: you sure you have the cookies script as you did not list it in the first comment if you do have it i will check your code again.

Comment: Before, I add `angular-cookies.js` for `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors`. But now I remove this from project. How can I fix this error?

Comment: you removed what ? angular-cookies.js is not for $httpProvider.responseInterceptors it is for ngCookies module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59151/discussion-between-mgh-and-user2918388).